# Hide file or directory in UNIX

Tags: unix

I am new to UNIX. I want to create some privileges on a folder.I have created a file in a directory, now I want to hide it for all users. I am unable to do that.
Please Help.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

There is no `hidden` attribute on Unix. But by convention, all files or directories starting with a dot `.` are considered hidden. Like `.gitconfig` for instance. Shells and `ls` are respecting this convention, so

```
cat *
```

does not print "dotfiles" and

```
ls
```

does not list "dotfiles".

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by 'hide'?  If you want users to be unable to see the contents of the file, do  `chmod -r file`.  They will still be able to see any links to the file if they list the directory.  (Keep in mind that there may be links to the file by a different name, but accessing the file through any of those links will fail since the user does not have read permission.)  If you want the link (aka "the filename") not to appear when someone lists the directory, remove read permissions on the directory.  Since your question states that you want to create privileges on a directory (sometimes incorrectly referred to as a 'folder'), you probably want the latter.  But removing read privileges on a directory does not make the contents of the file inaccessible, and if someone knows the names of the file in the directory they can access it.  In short, if you have a file named '/p/a/t/h/foo', and you want to ensure that no user (other than root) can see either the name `foo` nor the content of `foo`, you can do:

```
chmod -r /p/a/t/h       # Make the directory unreadable
chmod -r /p/a/t/h/foo   # Make the file unreadable
```

Note that removing read permissions on the directory makes all filenames in the directory unreadable, but that is the finest granularity you can get using conventional access permissions.  If necessary, put the file you are interested in in its own subdirectory to get finer control.

Simply adding a '.' to the start of the filename accomplishes almost nothing.  As a convention (originally a bug), `ls` will not display filenames that start with `.`, but those files are listed with `ls -a`, so this is probably not what you want.